# Performing recursive function on input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, input

I'm trying to run a recursive function that calculates the factorial of a number on an HTML input. I already know how to do it via iteration, I want to achieve the result recursively. But when I do it this way, I get a 'too much recursion' error. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" name="factorial_input" placeholder="Enter a number">
    <div class="button" onclick="calculateFactorial()">Let's see the factorial</div>
```

**JS**

```
function calculateFactorial(getInputValue) {
getInputValue = document.querySelector("input").value;

if (!getInputValue) {
    console.log("You must enter a number");
} else if (getInputValue == 0) {
    return console.log("1");
} else {
    return console.log(getInputValue *= calculateFactorial(getInputValue - 1));
}

// console.log(getInputValue);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having endless recursion issues because you are retrieving the value from input in recursive function and that's why the `getInputValue` variable gets fresh value every time. It's the wrong implementation you did. Try the example given below.

#### The HTML

```html
<input type="text" name="factorial_input" placeholder="Enter a number">
<div class="button" onclick="calculateFactorial()">Let's see the factorial</div>
```

#### The Script

```js
function calculateFactorial(getInputValue) {
    let getInputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector("input").value);
    console.log(fact(getInputValue));
}

function fact(n){
    if (n === undefined) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n *= fact(n - 1);
    }
}
```

The recursive function needs a satisfactory condition to return from recusrion to return the call stack. Otherwise, It'll go to the endless call.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't think of using a function call within another function. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why are you having getInputValue as the function parameter if you are not passing it to the function anyway?

Don't mix things together, it only makes things harder to understand.

Instead make a factorial function that only calculates factorial value, pass input's value to the function then console.log() it out.

```
function factorial(number) {
  return number == 1 || number == 0 ? number : number * factorial(number - 1);
}
```